# html and php input type submit doesn't work

Tags: php, html, input

perhaps a simple question but I cant find an explanation:
I have a php gallery application to make. One of the functions of the gallery is to show the miniatures of all uploaded photos. Every photo has to have a checkbox near it and there has to be a button that leads to a php script which does something like: show only checked photos in a new tab.

My problem is that the submit button doesn't work and I dont know what's the problem

EDIT: ok some more info what doesnt work: the buttons and the gallery show up, it's just the button doesnt run the script session.php when clicked. 
Here is the code:

```
echo '<form name ="gallery" method="post" action="session.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {

    echo ($i+1).'. <img src="'.$files[$i].'" />  '; 
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="gallery" value="'.($i+1).'">';
    echo "<br/>";

}
echo '<input type="submit" form = "gallery" name = "showchecked" value="button1" >';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: You have invalid HTML, that might be the cause of your problem. And `nctype="multipart/form-data"` seems unnecessary since you don't have any file inputs. Also, you have a closing `a` tag but no opening one.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a very insightful description.

Comment: Try to add opening `<a>` tag. I have modified it in answer

Comment: check your error logs.. and remove if there are any redirects in session.php so you can see the errors..

Comment: How do you know that `session.php` is not running when the form is submitted?

Comment: All your checkboxes have the same name, only the last (checked) will be submitted. Either give every checkbox a unique name (e.g. by appending the number) or make an array (`name="gallery[]"`).

Comment: What DOES happen when you click the button?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it's all ok now, thanks. I've done as you told me - how do I refer to this gallery array now? I want to use those checked photos in the script run when clicking the submit button

Comment: Might I ask why you close the input void tag with a `/>` but the image void tag without? It seems ppl mix XHTML and HTML5 a lot without knowing the difference..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `echo '<input type="submit" name="showchecked" value="button1" >';` (without the `form = "gallery"` bit).

If I am correct you should only use `form="yourform"` when an input field / button is outside the actual form and this is only supported in HTML5. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.submit.html (Thanks Gerald)

And as Gerald mentioned in a comment, your checkboxes all have the same name, you should either give them all a different name or do `name="gallery[]"`.

Comment: I'd count w3.org as a "decent source": http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.submit.html

Answer (score 0):

You are missing starting `<a>` tag here.

```
echo ($i+1).'. <img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a>
```

Right form will be

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {

echo "<a>"; // add this
echo ($i+1).'. <img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a>  ';
```

Comment: those are just typos from simplifying the code for stackoverflow, sorry, gonna edit those ones out

Comment: You should provide your code without typos. Otherwise you are getting wrong answers!